# SQL join to multipe columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables like this:

```
tbl_base
id      primary_id
aaaa     
bbbb
cccc 
dddd     eeee

tbl_current
id      current_id
aaaa    
bbbb    qqqq
cccc
dddd    zzzz

tbl_results
id     value
aaaa    10
cccc    20
dddd    50
zzzz    10
eeee     5
```

I have a table of results (`tbl_results`) that match to a given ID.  I want to join this data to `tbl_base`.  Unfortunately, there are four possible ID's that could appear in tbl_results:

1. tbl_base.id
2. tbl_base.primary_id
3. tbl_current.current_id (tbl_current.id = tbl_base.id)
4. tbl_current.current_id (tbl_current.id = tbl_base.primary_id)

I want to build a left join for `tbl_results` to `tbl_base`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_base
LEFT JOIN tbl_results
  ON tbl_results.id = tbl_base_id
...
```

What is the most efficient way to construct the query so that I join `tbl_results.id` to the four possible permutations of ID's present?  I tried:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  tbl_base
LEFT JOIN tbl_current
  ON tbl_current.id = tbl_base.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_results
  ON (tbl_results.id = tbl_base.id OR 
      tbl_results.id = tbl_base.primary_id OR
      tbl_results.id = tbl_current.id OR
      tbl_results.id = tbl_current.current_id)
```

This doesn't work.  The problem is that these tables are large in real life with millions of records and possible connections between all the ID's.  I cannot change the structure of the tables in any way - I'm just working with the system I'm given.  Any thoughts on how to do this with maximum efficiency?  I just want to return any rows in `tbl_results` where it's ID matches any of the four possible ID's.

**UPDATE:**

This is the output I'm after:

```
id     value
aaaa     10
bbbb     NULL
cccc     20
dddd     50 --from 'dddd'
dddd     10 --from 'zzzz'
```

Comment: I vote for union query.

Comment: how does the query not work?

Comment: Please show the desired Output. It is not completely clear how the tables interact. In your example data there are no matches between tbl_base and table_current, as table_current.current_id does nowhere exist in table_base. Is that true?

Comment: @Andrew - the query runs out of available memory if I do four separate left joins, and it just takes forever (never completed) using the OR's.

Comment: Could you provide more context for "maximum efficiency"?  If providing a WHERE clause in normal usage that greatly limits the number of rows returned (e.g., on the scale of 100's of rows), then this query should be ok as written.  If this query is going to return an extremely large number of rows when executed, it's important to know the context (is it an online job where a user is waiting?).  If the query as written is not performant, one option you should look into would be the equivalent of materialized views in oracle that use immediate refresh.  Not sure on sql server feature for that.

Comment: Will do, @ThorstenKettner.  For example, in tbl_base, there is id 'dddd'.  It equates to current_id 'zzzz'.  Then in tbl_results, zzzz has a value of 10.  I want to tie this number of the original entry in tbl_base under 'dddd'

Comment: @DanBracuk, how would that work?

Comment: @Jeffrey-Kramer, also to add to my comment above, make sure you have good indices for all the joined columns.

Comment: @DavidF I would design it much differently but unfortunately this is all I have to work with and I can't modify it at all.  :(

Comment: Can you run it with just one of the criteria?  If so, you can try the union, as Dan suggested.  You can also do an explain to see where bottlenecks are.

Comment: I'm going to try the UNION, I hadn't thought of that, and I think it might do the job, especially since I need everything returned from the LEFT join.  That seems like a great idea the more I consider it.

Comment: Don't your results lack dddd     5 --from 'eeee'?

Comment: The UNION solution worked perfectly.  Do you want to write up an answer @DanBracuk?  I can post mine but you deserve credit.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have posted your desired output:

```
select distinct tbl_both.id, tbl_results.value from
(
  select id, primary_id as secondary_id from tbl_base
  union all
  select id, current_id as secondary_id from tbl_current
) tbl_both
left outer join tbl_results on tbl_results.id in (tbl_both.id, tbl_both.secondary_id);
```

I haven't tested this. Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It seems to work, but I run out of memory and the UNION solution worked perfectly.